# Generate UILabel text when picking image

Tags: ios, uilabel, uiimagepickercontroller

I want an app that generates a random text from an array to a UILabel when I pick an image through UIImagePicker, just like the Look alike apps works. 
Can someone give me a good tutorial or explain how I should do?

Thanks

Comment: The question is in danger of being closed, for being too vague. You would improve the chances of keeping it open (or reopening it) if you can be specific about what parts you need help with (e.g. selecting a random item from an array) and show what you've tried or researched so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have an array that contains a bunch of strings and you want to randomly grab an object in it after you pick an image in the UIImagePickerController (correct?):

1.)Grab the number of objects in your array of strings.

2.)Generate a random number from 0 to the number of objects in the array using arc4random.

3.)Grab the string you have stored at that index in the array.

4.)Then set whichever UILabel you have set up to hold that text:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
   int numberOfObjects = self.yourArrayOfStrings.count;

   NSInteger randomNumberInRange = arc4random() % numberOfObjects;

   NSString *randomText = [yourArray objectAtIndex:randomNumberInRange];

   self.yourLabel.text = randomText;
}
```